# Maximum limit on number of people can access a public Google spreadsheet?

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I am developing an application which fetchs data from Google Spreadsheet using query.

The data comes in JSON format. I want to know whether there is any restrictions on number of request that can be sent to **Google server** for fetching the **JSON from the spreadsheets**. 
I mean **is there any restrictions like per hour or per day N requests**.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen a limit and suspect there is no such limit, but might be wrong.

Any ideas of rough volumes? I have has about 10 people at once use the service, it did slowdown a little, but was ok.

If it helps, the gdata style spreadsheet API takes about 1 Second/read and 2-10seconds/write (large sheets are slower)

Comment: I am developing an application which may fetch JSON data from the spreadsheet in every 30 seconds. Means 1 request per 30 seconds.

Comment: To test the idea, this code should help: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java Uses older style Auth, use a per application style password.